# How to use case insensitive dropdown selectize

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have one dropdown with an options like "Pediatrics". My page is receiving a query parameters as "pediatrics" (lower case).

When I try to set my the selection of my dropdown to Pediatrics, nothings happens, because the dropdown do not have pediatrics.

Ex:

```
<div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="Pediatrics">Pediatrics</div>
```

I`m trying to select this options using:

```
let myParamS = "pediatrics";

$("#specialization").data('selectize').setValue(myParamS);
```

=> Will not work, beucase my dropdown have "P"ediatrics instead of "p"ediatrics

Anyone know what is the best way to set this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through options with case insensitive comparison, and find the right option value to set.

```
let myParamS = "pediatrics";

const selectizeInput = $("#specialization").data('selectize');
// returns a dictionary of options with value as a key
const options = selectizeInput.options; 

// does case insensitive comparision to find the matching option
const getValue = (options, valueToFind) => Object.keys(options)
.find(key => key.toLowerCase() === valueToFind.toLowerCase());

// set value
selectizeInput.setValue(getValue(options, myParamS));
```